# Shopify tablerow loop exiting early

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

I'm looping through my collection of frontpage products and generating a table. In the last row, I need to put some static content in the first table cell. I've been able to do that, but for some reason, the loop stops after it does that. Does anyone know why?

```
  {% tablerow product in collections.frontpage.products cols: 2 %}
    {% if tablerowloop.col_first and tablerowloop.last %}
      <img src="{{'box.png' | asset_url}}">
    {% else %}
      <div class='featured-product'>
        <img src="{{ product.images[1] | product_img_url: 'medium' }}">
        <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endtablerow %}
```

Here's the site: https://hodkiewicz-zieme-and-hirthe180.myshopify.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tablerowloop.last` only returns true for the last cell of the table (i.e. last product of the collection), not for the last row.  Instead you need to check if the index within `cols` of the end of the collection, such that it must be the last row if it is the first column.

```
{% tablerow product in collections.frontpage.products cols: 2 %}
  {% assign x = tablerowloop.length | minus:2 %}
  {% if tablerowloop.col_first and tablerowloop.index > x %}
    <img src="{{'box.png' | asset_url}}">
  {% else %}
    <div class='featured-product'>
      <img src="{{ product.images[1] | product_img_url: 'medium' }}">
      <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endtablerow %}
```

Comment: Okay, I understand the first part, that tablerowloop.last only returns for the last cell of the table. But, that doesn't make sense to me since it outputs the static content correctly and then the loop dies prematurely.

Comment: Your frontpage collection only has 5 products, so a two column table only has one product in the last row.  Since the if condition matches, that product is replaced by the box.png asset image.  It isn't prematurely dying, but perhaps you wanted the to also show the product after the box.png image, in which case you can move the else block out of the if condition.